# Hide one of hosted app part from solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, custom-web-part-property

I have developed a solution which have 20 SharePoint hosted app part. Now i want to hide one of the app-part from this hosted app solution, so that user can not see and add that one app part on page. Is it possible to hide it by specifying some property in XML of hosted app.? without removing the web-part from solution.?
Thanks!

Comment: have you developed these as SPFx webparts ?

Comment: No. I have developed it with SharePoint hosted model.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `<!-- -->`  to achieve it.

For example, edit the client web part Elements.xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<!--<ClientWebPart Name="ClientWebPart2" Title="ClientWebPart01172 Title" Description="ClientWebPart2 Description" DefaultWidth="300" DefaultHeight="200">
      <Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/ClientWebPart2.aspx?{StandardTokens}" />
      <Properties>
      </Properties>
    </ClientWebPart>-->
</Elements>
```